# Shoreditch looks different in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, extension, shoreditch

The contact screen in shoreditch on wordpress looks like this;
Different from the screens i find on the extension page. Is there a reason, or am I doing something wrong?
[image]

Comment: Civi's WordPress layout has always been different from Drupal's, and I guess the main focus of Shoreditch is on the latter as the majority of people use that. Hopefully one of the team will let us know about WordPress support.

Comment: Any news? Or prospect?

Comment: Last I saw, Shoreditch for Drupal was due to go final very soon: https://civicrm.org/blog/jamienovick/going-shoreditch-civicrms-new-ux-design-comes-to-life-pt-1-of-2. Jamie says "We've mainly tested this initial Shoreditch release on the Drupal user interface but we'll shortly be putting up a make it happen for full testing for Joomla and Wordpress compatibility. Whilst we believe that Shoreditch should mostly work on Joomla and Wordpress, we'd welcome feedback and bug reports for when we do start that work"

Answer (score 3):

The documentation in Shoreditch states:

> Requirements
>
> - Drupal 7
> - CiviCRM, v5.0+ recommended
> - "CiviCRM Theme" module enabled
> - "Seven" theme set as CiviCRM Administration theme

My understanding is that the layout part is then heavily depending on the Seven theme, which is why it appears so differently in WordPress. Please correct if this is a misunderstanding.

If you use the [CiviCRM Admin Utilites plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/), you can enable WP Admin Styles, [published blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/danaskallman/wordpress-admin-styles-for-civicrm-with-wordpress) with an overview.

[image: CAU Settings]

[image: Contact Record Sample]

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension from bgm: https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch-wordpress-workarounds

It's working better than the CiviCRM Admin Utilities WP-Plugin.